# Strapi E-Mail templating EJS does print content, but fails on conditions

Tags: ejs, strapi

I am currently extending a small strapi.io project with an confirmation email. Coded a hook, configured the mail provider and rendered the information I needed with EJS in a template - all fun an games until now:

I must not execute a condition. For example:

```
<% if(true){ %>
  <h1>foo</h1>
 <% } else{ %>
  <h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

does not seem to be interpreted and look like this in a mail.

[image]

Glad for any ideas